# vb.net windows form automatic resizing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form in my vb.net application which has recently started resizing itself dependant on the computers screen resolution.

I would like the form to be a fixed width and height - how can i make it do this and not resize itself?

Comment: Do you have some property such as Maximized set?

Comment: You'll have to stop trying to prevent it from doing the right thing, DPI awareness and virtualization are important today.  That window turns into a completely unusable postage stamp on a 4K monitor if you fight it.

Comment: Before it was removed, there was an answer to this question that said to try setting the window to fixedsingle, and you commented that you had already tried that.....you should include what you have already tried in your original question in order to help those who are trying to help you.

Comment: i hadnt tried this - it was already set to that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to change the property AutoScaleMode.
The default is FONT (the correct to most different systems DPI), but you may try other options there.

**UPDATE**

I saw now you may set the PROPERTIES of a file in the DESKTOP to "Deactivate Dimmension in High-DPI Settings" (it´s translated from Portuguese, my system). Click in the desktop application´s properties (its icon) and go to COMPATIBILITY TAB.

It´s not a .NET solution but if Windows had put it there, is because it´s possible the only way to set it.

Comment: i have tried all of these options but i still get the same issue

Comment: You may try to calculate a correlation between you form and resolution/DPI.  For instance, if you divide Screen.Width/MyForm.Width and Screen.Height/MyForm.Height you will have a kind of indexes.  Using theses indexes you may have an approximated calculation to adapt your form - but the risk is to have you application to small in a 4k monitor.

Comment: Why don´t you consider your application can be resized by user, making all controls within be positioned according the final size?